# Retrieving column in deleted/inserted tables referencing another table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

It may save some time to skip the "why" on this.

I would like to compile a string within a SQL Server trigger that contains all the values in the inserted or deleted tables, including their column names.  I'm not used to doing something this extensive in SQL so I may be approaching this entirely wrong.

Something like:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIGGER_NAME]
ON [MY_TABLE_NAME]
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @columns TABLE(COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(100))

    INSERT INTO @columns
        SELECT
            COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE
            TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'

    DECLARE @string nvarchar(MAX)
    SET @string = (SELECT TOP 1 
                       STRING_AGG(CONCAT('s:', LEN(COLUMN_NAME), ':"', 
                                         COLUMN_NAME, '";', inserted.COLUMN_NAME), ';' )
                   FROM @columns)
```

This doesn't tell the full story, but the critical piece is the `inserted.COLUMN_NAME` part. The value in `COLUMN_NAME` is a varchar and I want that value to be evaluated as the name of the column in the inserted table.

I explored writing a function or stored procedure but fear I may be overthinking this. It feels like a basic thing to do. In javascript I'd simply say something like inserted[Column_Name] but SQL is a whole different beast...

--EDIT--

What I want is to be able to evaluate the value held in a variable as a column name. i.e.

```
DECLARE @var varchar(50)
SET $var = 'name';
```

`SELECT TABLE_NAME.$var` (should get the column named 'name' from table named TABLE_NAME)

Ultimate goal is to...

Say there is a table like this:

| Row NUM | Email | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack@name.com | Jack |
| 2 | Jill@name.com | Jill |

I want to be able to be able convert this table into a single string like this without knowing all the names of the columns ahead of time.

```
'Email:Jack@name.com,Name:Jack;Email:Jill@name.com,Name:Jill;'
```

Comment: Don't fully follow your code and I'm not sure what you're stuck on. Could you please clarify and provide an example string of the results you'd expect?

Comment: "It may save some time to skip the 'why' on this.". Ah... aiding and abetting data crimes. Got it. That said, might I suggest a non-relational approach? That is, how about doing something like `declare @x xml = (select * from inserted for xml path('__row__'), type` and then jam that into a table to track your changes. You could also do `for json path` instead if you're more comfortable with that.